Update R version running on ubuntu in a conda environment
Firstly, I'd like to mention this has been previously posted in the Ubuntu forum with no replies, so I thought I'd try my luck here.
I currently use ubuntu as a linux subsystem on my windows machine.
I run a conda environment (qiime2) which uses R. Recently, I realized that one of the R packages used by qiime2 was built under a newer version compared to what I currently have:
Warning message:package ‘optparse’ was built under R version 4.2.3 R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
I updated my R version based on the instructions here: https://gcore.com/learning/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu/
But when I check the R --version it defaults back to the older version:
(qiime2-amplicon-2023.9) angelica@angelica_xps15:~/GQ_fastq/qiime_gq$ R --version
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31) -- "Innocent and Trusting" Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
I installed the new R version outside of the conda environment with no issue:
(base) angelica@angelica_xps15:~/GQ_fastq/qiime_gq$ R --version
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31) -- "Pile of Leaves" Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Any advice on what could be happening?
Best,
Angelica

Does it have to be Conda?  You get better R support natively, see about the key binaries from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ and then the binary packages from https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u .  Many people use this just fine with WSL2.

The link "How to Install R on Ubuntu" helps to install R outside conda. For example in ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ or in /usr/local/lib/R/* /usr/lib/R/*. Type in R .libPaths() to know in each environnement where are your libs.

It seems that your base env reads the general R environnement. Your qiime2-amplicon-2023.9 env reads the R lib in  ~/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-amplicon-2023.9

To install R in a conda env you have to get the libs in ~/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-amplicon-2023.9 with https://docs.anaconda.com/working-with-conda/packages/using-r-language/ but R is yet installed in your case.  To update your R env type conda activate qiime2-amplicon-2023.9  and type R (equivalent to something like  ~/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-amplicon-2023.9/bin/R)  and inside install.packages('optparse').

Or try to reinstall qiime : https://docs.qiime2.org/2024.10/install/native/
